# ¿Cómo elimino de una hoja css los estilos que no se usan en una página?

Tags: css

Usando en Chrome la opción de **Audits** puedo identificar las clases que no uso, pero ¿hay alguna manera de eliminarlas sin tener que hacerlo manualmente una por una?

Comment: Quizás esto te interesa: https://github.com/purifycss/purifycss

Comment: te recomiendo que te instales la herramienta PurifyCSS, es fácil de usar y super confiable. Acá te dejo un tutorial de su uso: https://webdesign.tutsplus.com/es/tutorials/remove-unnecessary-css-with-purifycss-and-grunt--cms-27726

Answer (score 4):

Puedes usar [gulp](http://gulpjs.com/) con [gulp-check-unused-css](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-check-unused-css).

También hay páginas online en las que te generan tus estilos sin el CSS que no usas: https://unused-css.com/.

Espero que te sea de utilidad.

Comment: Muchas Gracias, mi sitio aún está local así que no pude usar **unused-css**, se me hizo más fácil usar un complemento de Firefox que marca la línea y la clase que no se usa, aún es un poco tardado pero ya con el número de linea puedo ir seleccionando y eliminando por bloques. << **CSS Coverage** >>

Comment: Realmente la mejor manera y la más automática es usar gulp. Con él podrás hacerlo de forma automática y te generará el CSS en local para luego poder utilizarlo en producción.